# mysql event to change a fields value when a date is reached

Tags: mysql, events, date, field, default-value

What I am trying to accomplish is this:
I have table1 which contains user_id,group_id(int with a default value set) and expire_date.Also table2 which between others has a field user_group_id which serves as foreign key to group_id of table1.

When the date is reached I'd like to change values of group_id and user_group_id to default.

Unfortunately it seems I can't figure my way around this since I'm really new to mysql.

Table1 will contain like 500 rows max.Probably the event won't be used to update more than 4-5 rows per run.

Automated alternative solutions are welcome.
mysql  5.2.7
php    5.3.8
CentOs 6

Thanks in advance for any responces!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it with event.

```
CREATE EVENT event_name2
  ON SCHEDULE 
   EVERY 24 HOUR
   DO
    UPDATE test.employees
    SET `group`=DEFAULT
    WHERE expire_date <= now( )
```

Firstly i thought to use triggers but they occur only when something is changed on database witch wasnt the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You need a statement like

```
update table1 set group_id=<default> where expire_date() > now();
```

You can run this update query from a cronjob or from a trigger or from a mysql event (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)